# Reading input value from textbox, fetching the data from Textfile and displaying the result

Tags: c#

I need help in searching the text file. I have manage to store the input values to Textfile with `":"` separator.

And my result text box is like

```
friend1:126457890
friend2:123487012
Friend3:798461598
```

and now I want to search the text file and display result in `labels/textbox(read only)`

Here is my code to search

```
 private void btn_search_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_search.Text))
            {
                lbl_search_error.Text = "Please Enter name to search";
            }
            else
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"path.txt");

                string line;
                string searchkey = txt_search.Text;
                sr.ReadToEnd();

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    if (line.Contains(searchkey))
                        break;
                }
                sr.Close();

                string[] data = line.Split(':');
                txt_result_name.Text = data[0];
                txt_result_phno.Text = data[1];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_search_error.Text = ex.Message;
        }
}
```

but I get

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

I tried to keep break point and chk, error is in this line

```
string[] data = line.Split(':');
```

Please help resolving

Thank you for your time

Comment: All you want is to retrieve the name and number from each line and display it in a text box right?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: yes, sr.ReadLine() will (eventually) read to end (or at least til you break it) since it is in a while loop. If you need to read beyond your break, just can handle this separately. The problem is that sr.ReadToEnd() moves the cursor to the end of the file. Afterwards sr.ReadLine() will always return null as you are already at the end.

Comment: Awesome it resolved the issue..! (i can not vote up tough its giving error)<br>

well now, the search works like this,

whatever you give the inputs..its returning  the 1st result of 1st line of the textbox..

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a different approach using regular expression:

```
   private void btn_search_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Some file");
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string name="";
        string number="";
        while (line != null)
        {
            var m = Regex.Match(line, @"([\w]+):([\d]+)<br>");
            if (m.Success)
            {
                name = m.Groups[1].Value; 
                number = m.Groups[2].Value;   // use this name and number variables as per your need
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            else
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a way to go about the problem. Ask any questions if you have

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the value of `line` is `null` in: `string[] data = line.Split(':');`

Take a string variable called `temp` and assign the value of `line` to `temp` in the while loop. Later use this variable instead of `line`.
Do like this:

```
 private void btn_search_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_search.Text))
            {
                lbl_search_error.Text = "Please Enter name to search";
            }
            else
            {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"path.txt");

                string line;
                string searchkey = txt_search.Text;
                sr.ReadToEnd();


                string temp;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                   if (line.Contains(searchkey))
                   {
                      temp = line;
                      break;
                   }
                }
                sr.Close();

                string[] data = temp.Split(':');
                txt_result_name.Text = data[0];
                txt_result_phno.Text = data[1];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_search_error.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @^ with that code i get the error : "use of unassigned local 'temp' variable" .. i have declared string temp tough..well i have not down voted..idk who did that

Comment: u mean this.. `code` string line;
                    string temp;
                    string searchkey = txt_search.Text;
                 //   sr.ReadToEnd();


                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        if (line.Contains(searchkey))
                            temp = line;
                            break;
                    }
                    sr.Close();